# Search query in react not searching in all posts after implanting infinity loading

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Search query in react . not searching in all posts after implanting infinity loading

the fronted part react just search in first 10 posts

after i implant infinity loading in my react app this happened to me

I have 3 file that related to this problem

one of them is my Post.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../../common/LoadingSpinner';
import PostsList from '../../../common/PostsList';
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
import Postslistxx from '../../Tag/Postlistsxx';
import PostsListposts from './PosListposts';
PostsListposts

const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  const { data: posts, isLoading } = useGetPostsQuery(null, {
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    filteredPosts && <PostsListposts posts={filteredPosts} enableImages={false} />
  );
};

const Wrapper = tw.div`bg-blue`;

export default Posts;
```

and of of them is Postlistposts.jsx

```
import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import tw from 'twin.macro';
Placeholder
Post  
import Placeholder from '../../../common/Placeholder/Placeholder';
import Post from '../../PostPage/components/Post';
import PostsList from '../../../common/PostsList/PostsList';

const PostsListposts = ({ posts, filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {posts?.length > 0 ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => (
          <PostsList
            post={post}
            isFirstPost={enableImages && i === 0}
            filteredTag={filteredTag}
            key={nanoid()}
            toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
          />
        ))
      ) : (
        <Placeholder />
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full`;

export default PostsListposts;
```

and another one is my file that related to infinity loading

is my Postlist.jsx

```
import { nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import tw from "twin.macro";
import Advertise from "../../pages/PostPage/components/Advertise";
import Placeholder from "../Placeholder";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import rehypeVideo from "rehype-video";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "../LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner";





// import AutoDarkMode from 'auto-dark-mode';
// const theme = null; // will apply the default one
// // some elemens may got corrupted so double rotate them 
// const doubleRotatedElements = ['img', 'video']; 
// new AutoDarkMode(theme, doubleRotatedElements);
  






// import ArticleSkeleton from './ArticleSkeleton';
const PostsList = ({ filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  const advertise = async () => {
    window?.EventBus?.emit("reset-ads");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    advertise();
  }, []);

  const [posts, setposts] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        let skip = posts.length;
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=5&skip=${skip}`)
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setposts([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);




  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts`)
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts");
      
      const data = await res.json();

      setposts(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);



  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {
        posts?.length > 0 ? (
          posts.map((post, i) => (
            <>
              <>
                <Post
                  post={post}
                  isFirstPost={enableImages && i++}
                  filteredTag={filteredTag}
                  key={nanoid()}
                  toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
                />
                <Advertise />
              </>
            </>
          ))
        ) : (
          <>
            <LoadingSpinner />
          </>
        )
        // (

        //   <Placeholder />

        // )
      }
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full`;

export default PostsList;
```

and

the file in the backend part of website that related to infinity loading and query limmit and skip is

```
const getPost = async (req, res) => {
  const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
  const authorId = await author?.toObject({ getters: true }).id;
  const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

  const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
    author: authorId,
    title: postTitle,
    _id: postId,
  })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("comments")
    .populate("tags")
    .exec();

  res.status(200).json(foundPost?.toObject({ getters: true }));
};
```

I can not understand what did i do wrong . why after I added infinity loading with react fetch api , search stopped working

the only way i can make search works is change the limmit to all records in database and google chrome hang because of too many records

. what is my problem can some one understand this